# "This app requires iOS 11.3" and I am using 11.3.3

Tags: ios, swift, deployment

Just launched my new app. It downloads fine on my iPhone (6) and iPad (3). Then I tried to download it to my kids' iPads (2) and I get an error saying that `this app requires iOS 11.3 or higher`, even though the iOS on the device is `11.3.3`.

When I created the build for upload to the iTunes Connect, I used my phone (iPhone 6, iOS 11.3.3), and `deployment target was set to 11.3`.

Any ideas on what to do?

Should I instead create the build using for example an iPad2 instead, and select an earlier deployment target version?

Please bear in mind that I'm quite a novice at this.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Just set the deployment target for example to 10.2. You don't need to use a real device to build a version for the store, you can also use the "Generic iOS Device" scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Much appreciated.
Since I've already launched the version to iTunes Connect, could I just create a version 1.1, and select deployment target to 10.2. Will it not matter that version 1.0 was for 11.3?
Where do I select 'Generic iOS Device'?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Much appreciated. Since I've already launched the version to iTunes Connect, could I just create a version 1.1, and select deployment target to 10.2. Will it not matter that version 1.0 was for 11.3? Where do I select 'Generic iOS Device'? Thanks for your help

Comment: I think your iPad iOS version is 10.3.3, current iOS version is 11.3.1 not 11.3.3...

Comment: You're absolutely right, also please see my comment further down.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Thomas, first of all you don't actually need an `device to make a build to submit to app store` just select the `Generic iOS Device on Xcode` to make it work.

Secondly its strange even if you have set the `target to 11.3 its not running on devices using **11.3.1**` the latest is 11.3.1 I guess **not** `11.3.3` just check for below screenshots hopefully it will help you in case.[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is 10.3.3. Sorry about that.
So I could just make a new build, selecting 10.2 as deployment target, and then generic device, and then submit it as version 1.1.

Is that about right?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes ,It will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks, and no problem in launching a 'new' version where the target is an older version of iOS, now that I've already launched for the 11.3?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: No, it won't effect anythings is just means your app will now support iPhones/iPads to running iOS 10 now.

Comment: Thanks so much with your help :)

Comment: please upvote the answer, if it solves the concern, thanks in advance :D

Comment: Thanks. Just tried, and got a message saying it was recorded but not publicly displayed since my account is rather new. So hope you got the points anyway :)